# Упорядочить элементы списка

Tags: java, сортировка, список

public void sort() { ... } - упорядочивает элементы списка в порядке возрастания (в соответствии с порядком, определенным интерфейсом Comparable).

```
public void sort() {
Node<E> small = head;
    int k = 0;
    while((small.next)!=null){
        if (small.info.compareTo(small.next.info)>0){
            small = small.next;
            k++;

            Node<E> big = head;
            int n = 0;
                while(big.info.compareTo(small.info)<0) {
                    big = big.next;
                    n++;

                }
            swap(n,k);
        }
        else{
            small = small.next;
            k++;
```

я вот так я написала, но он не хочет его сортировать, почему? Он даже в нормальном виде не выводит список :(

```
public void swap(int i, int j) {
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= size || j >= size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if (i > j) {
        int t = i;
        i = j;
        j = t;
    }

    Node<E> prevI = find(new Node(head), i);
    Node<E> nodeI = prevI.next;
    Node<E> nextI = nodeI.next;
    Node<E> prevJ = find(prevI, j - i);
    Node<E> nodeJ = prevJ.next;
    Node<E> nextJ = nodeJ.next;

    System.out.println(nodeI.info + " " + nodeJ.info);

    if (i + 1 == j) {
        prevI.next = nodeJ;
        nodeJ.next = nodeI;
        nodeI.next = nextJ;
    } else {
        prevI.next = nodeJ;
        nodeJ.next = nextI;
        prevJ.next = nodeI;
        nodeI.next = nextJ;
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        head = nodeJ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите реализацию метода swap (добавьте, пожалуйста, его в ваш вопрос)

Comment: @Vadik , Я добавила